# Prefers reduced motions media query didn't let me to have a Bootstrap modal with animation

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Bootstrap 4 modals`, the problem I have is there not showing the `fade animation` and slide animation. I was searching and I find the problem. In the `transitions.scss` file there are a media queries that's are applying called @media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce). These query make the transition fade didn't happens, so it shows like that:

```
@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)
.fade {
    transition: none;
}
```

You can see the live example for testing and developing [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/habitaciones.php): (Click on aviso legal, condiciones, privacidad... link and you will see it).
It happen's automatically, how I can disable it and make the animations works?

Comment: It seems to be fading fine for me in Chrome … which is no surprise, since _I_ don’t have my Chrome configured to request that sites use less “motion” to begin with. Bootstrap is trying to respect the user’s wishes here - and so should you. This setting is meant to help people who have _problems_ with too much motion/animations/moving stuff on a website.

Comment: So how I can disable that setting on my Chrome?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/prefers-reduced-motion#remove_motion_on_operating_systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@04FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10955263/04fs) indicated, you will need to [disable reduced motion on your operating system](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/prefers-reduced-motion#remove_motion_on_operating_systems) to view the animation. If at all possible, please do not override this in your CSS because of the obvious accessibility implications.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to disable it on my Mac settings. Thanks to all!